# Python: Using `copyreg` to define reducers for types that already have reducers

Tags: python, function, pickle

(Keep in mind I'm working in Python 3, so a solution needs to work in Python 3.)

I would like to use the `copyreg` module to teach Python how to pickle functions. When I tried to do it, the `_Pickler` object would still try to pickle functions using the `save_global` function. (Which doesn't work for unbound methods, and that's the motivation for doing this.)

It seems like `_Pickler` first tries to look in its own `dispatch` for the type of the object that you want to pickle before looking in `copyreg.dispatch_table`. I'm not sure if this is intentional.

Is there any way for me to tell Python to pickle functions with the reducer that I provide?

Answer (score 1):

The following hack seems to work in Python 3.1...:

```
import copyreg
def functionpickler(f):
  print('pickling', f.__name__)
  return f.__name__

ft = type(functionpickler)
copyreg.pickle(ft, functionpickler)

import pickle
pickle.Pickler = pickle._Pickler
del pickle.Pickler.dispatch[ft]

s = pickle.dumps(functionpickler)
print('Result is', s)
```

Out of this, the two hackish lines are:

```
pickle.Pickler = pickle._Pickler
del pickle.Pickler.dispatch[ft]
```

You need to remove the `dispatch` entry for functions' type because otherwise it preempts the copyreg registration; and I don't think you can do that on the C-coded Pickler so you need to set it to the Python-coded one.

It would be a bit less of a hack to subclass `_Pickler` with a class of your own which makes its own `dispatch` (copying the parent's and removing the entry for the function type), and then use your subclass specifically (and its dump method) rather than `pickle.dump`; however it would also be a bit less convenient that this monkeypatching of pickle itself.