# Is the copyreg module being used properly here?

Tags: python, windows, types, pickle

Can anyone tell me why my code and function serialization handlers are not working below? The `copyreg` module is fairly unfamiliar to me, and it is not clear if the code below is written properly.

```
>>> import pickle, copyreg, types, marshal
>>> def average(*args):
    return sum(args) / len(args)

>>> average_dump = pickle.dumps(average)
>>> del average
>>> average = pickle.loads(average_dump)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    average = pickle.loads(average_dump)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'average'
>>> copyreg.pickle(types.CodeType,
           lambda code: (marshal.loads, (marshal.dumps(code),)),
           marshal.loads)
>>> up = lambda co, ns, de, cl: types.FunctionType(co, globals(), na, de, cl)
>>> copyreg.pickle(types.FunctionType,
           lambda function: (up, (function.__code__,
                      function.__name__,
                      function.__defaults__,
                      function.__closure__)),
           up)
>>> def average(*args):
    return sum(args) / len(args)

>>> average_dump
b'\x80\x03c__main__\naverage\nq\x00.'
>>> pickle.dumps(average)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\naverage\nq\x00.'
>>> del average; average = pickle.loads(average_dump)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    del average; average = pickle.loads(average_dump)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'average'
```

My expectation is that if the registered functions were working properly, then both code and function objects would be serialized. If that worked as expected, unpickling functions would also be possible.

---

**Edit:** subclassing `Pickler` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933605/216356). Does not seem to help either. The function from the example is still being serialized by name instead of the handlers from the `copyreg` module.

```
>>> import pickle, copyreg, types, marshal
>>> copyreg.pickle(types.CodeType,
           lambda code: (marshal.loads, (marshal.dumps(code),)),
           marshal.loads)
>>> up = lambda co, ns, de, cl: types.FunctionType(co, globals(), na, de, cl)
>>> copyreg.pickle(types.FunctionType,
           lambda function: (up, (function.__code__,
                      function.__name__,
                      function.__defaults__,
                      function.__closure__)),
           up)
>>> class MyPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.dispatch_table = copyreg.dispatch_table


>>> def average(*args):
    return sum(args) / len(args)

>>> x = io.BytesIO(); y = MyPickler(x)
>>> y.dump(average)
>>> x.getvalue()
b'\x80\x03c__main__\naverage\nq\x00.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serialize functions, please run the following command:

```
pip install dill
```

Once done, you can `import dill` and use it in place of the `pickle` module.

If you are running Python 3 and want easy access to `pip`, put a batch file in your Windows directory named `pip.bat` and put the following line in it (assumes you have a proxy that interferes with SSL):

```
py -3 -m pip %* --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Answer (score -2):

Function's can't be pickled by-value:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. *Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled.* Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

(http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: I understand how they are currently pickled, but why does the `copyreg` module not obey my instructions to use the new handler?

Comment: I'd misunderstood, sorry. Maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2933605/257418